# link_to video in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

- I made a testing video with quickTime Player and named it: *`testing.mov`*
- I dragged that video into the root of my rails application

I now want to simply create a link to that video in a view. When that link is clicked, it will display the video.

I imagine this is a simple answer.  We played around with it and tried a number of things:

```
#neither work
link_to "My video", 'testing.mov'
link_to "My video", '<relative_path_to>testing.mov'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a `videos` folder in your `assets` directory and then put your `testing.mov` file there. You can then use either of the asset url helpers (`video_path` / `video_url`) in your `link_to` method. Here is an example:

```
link_to "My video", video_path("testing.mov")
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the video from the root of your Rails app into the `public` folder.

After that, `link_to "My video", 'testing.mov'` should work.